# Unsure about how to get intervals for roots for intermediate value theorem

Tags: calculus, limits, roots

Consider the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}+3^x-x^3-x^2.$ By inspection, $x=0$ is a root of $f(x)$. Show that $f(x)$ has at least three other roots and a vertical asymptote.

$\textbf{Solution:}$ This is not a hard question and I did fully solve it. Since $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 1^+}}f(x)=\infty$ and $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 1^-}}f(x)=-\infty$, we definitely know that $x=1$ is a vertical asymptote.

I'm not sure about how to show there are $3$ roots for $f(x)$. I know I can use the intermediate value theorem and show there is a sign change.

For example, I know that $f(0.05)=0.001$, $f(0.5)=-0.64$ so there is a root between $(0.05,0.5)$.

Similarly, $f(1.5)=1.57$, $f(2)=-2$ so there is a root between $(1.5,2)$.

$f(3)=-\frac{17}{2}$, $f(4)=\frac{4}{3}$ so there is a root between $(3,4)$.

So I've just proven that there at at least 3 roots.

The problem is that I basically used Wolfram alpha to get those intervals and use the Intermediate value theorem that way though. Is there a more nicer way of doing this that does not require me to use a calculator to get the intervals near that region? There should be some logical way I guess?

EDIT: Corrected $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}+3^x-x^2-x^2$ into $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}+3^x-x^3-x^2.$

Comment: Is it a typo in f(x) equation, there are two similar terms

Comment: I fixed the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x=1$ cannot be a root, it may be simpler to consider
$$g(x)=3^x (x-1)-(x^4-x^2+1)$$

By inspection
$$g(-2)=-\frac{34}{3} \qquad g(-1)=\frac{1}{3}\qquad g(0)=0\qquad g(1)=1$$ $$ g(2)=-2 \qquad g(3)=-17 \qquad g(4)=4$$

Answer (score 2):

Since we need roots of $f(x) = 0$
i.e, $$\frac{1}{x-1} +3^{x-1} - x^3 - x^2 = 0$$

Let's define

$$g(x) = x^3 + x^2 - \frac{1}{x-1} = \frac{x^4 - x^2 - 1}{x-1} $$

$$h(x) = 3^x$$

So now $f(x) = 0$ gives the same roots as $g(x) = h(x)$.

Now you can easily find solutions by analysing their graphs